# Work light Session Timeout

Tags: session, ibm-mobilefirst

When we change serverSessionTimeout value from worklight.properties files should be restart the worklight server for changes to effect?

Answer (score 0):

worklight.properties is part of the .war file. You are therefore required to re-deploy the .war file.

Depending on your underlying application server (Tomcat, WAS full profile, WAS Liberty profile), you may need to restart it. You will likely need to restart, yes.